# Project time tracker

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm building a project time tracker and need some guidance on how to record weekly hours.

I essentially have two tables: projectTable and weeklyReportTable with a one to many relation.

ProtectTable will keeping a record of all projects being worked on along with other information, such as owner, status, etc...

weeklyReportTable is supposed to keep a track of weekly activity on the project and there can only be one entry per week per project. On a weekly basis users will log number of hours and an activity report of what happened during that week.

The UI to update project status will consist of panel listing all projects by the logged in user along with an input field to log hours and activity. There will be a widget that the user can use to move forward and backward to select the week they want to log activity against.

Question: what would be the best approach to ensure that there is only one entry per week per project in the weeklyReportTable? If a user tried to log activity on a project for a week that already exists I don't want to create a new record but rather update the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answer above, that is what I would personally suggest.

If the entry is not yet there 
-> Create
else
-> Retrieve it
-> Update it

I did something similar at my own stand-alone app, check it at: http://www.prototimer.com

Comment: Linking your own project like that makes this answer look quite a bit like spam. The fact that you've posted two answers in a short amount of time which both link to your project imply that you are here primarily to promote your project. That's something which is really discouraged here. If you are wanting to contribute good quality answers and/or question, then this is a good place to be. If you are just wanting to promote your project, posts here really aren't where that should be done.

Comment: While you may link to your own project from your answer, the answer must actually answer the question  (you do) and the link must be relevant (not really; i.e. it doesn't really make the answer better) with your association with the project disclosed (you do). Please see: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).

Comment: I am sorry if you feel that way. In my opinion, the fact that I have developed this application (and have given proof to it with the link) and it is in production, lead me to provide a very precise answer to the question. I am also putting myself available to further answers in case the author have any further. I understand your point, but I am also trying to identify whether there is interest for such tool so that I could invest time in making this project open-source.

Comment: Feel free to remove my answers if you thnk it is hurting the quality of the community.

Answer (score 0):

if u have a project start date, I'd assume you want to create it when project gets created, ahead of time, till end date. Otherwise, you can create it when they click on a specific week, but you might want to lock that portion to make sure that in case two users, cannot click it, causing a duplicate value. Or you can write a trigger on the before create to check for a duplicate but still I think you want to lock it since relationship has a different cardinality than expressed through UI. If u have a custom database, specify a unique index on date + project id, as long as you use the same date (monday of the week u r in), you should be good

Comment: Sure, I will have a start date and an end date but for this question I'm mostly concerned about the weekly update. How do I avoid duplicates? How do I even query programmatically an object to see if it already exists in the table?